# Using Open Graph Protocol to extract og:image source

Tags: php, regex, github, facebook-opengraph

Using https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph

How do I access the individual array elements such as just the [image]

```
$graph = OpenGraph::fetch('http://www.avessotv.com.br/bastidores-pantene-institute-experience-pg.html');
print_r($graph);
```

Will return

```
OpenGraph Object    
(
    [_values:OpenGraph:private] => Array
        (
            [type] => article
            [video] => http://www.avessotv.com.br/player/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf..
            [image] => /wp-content/thumbnails/9025.jpg
            [site_name] => Programa Avesso - Bastidores
            [title] => Bastidores Ã¢Â€ÂœPantene Institute ExperienceÃ¢Â€Â P&G
            [url] => http://www.avessotv.com.br/bastidores-pantene-institute-experience-pg.html
            [description] => Confira os bastidores do Pantene Institute Experience, da Procter &#038; Gamble. www.pantene.com.br Mais imagens:
        )

    [_position:OpenGraph:private] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple as `$graph->type`, `$graph->video` etc.

from the documented source:

```
  /**
   * Helper method to access attributes directly
   * Example:
   * $graph->title
   *
   * @param $key    Key to fetch from the lookup
   */
  public function __get($key){
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [PHP magic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)

Use `$image_url = $graph->image;`